# Почему код не работает? Js

Tags: javascript, html5, img, setinterval

Это должно работать примерно так: Оно 1 раз проходит быструю загрузку(смену) картинки, а потом происходит медленная смена. Вообще проблема в том, что когда загружаешь страницу, вместо картинки пустое место и только после первой смены картинки она появляется. Помогите решить проблему[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
<script language="javascript">
    var img = 1, imgMax = 3;
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    let i=1;
    if(i!=0){setInterval(function() {
        image.src = (++img > imgMax ? (img = 1) : img) + '.jpg';
        }, 1000);
        i--;
    } else {
        setInterval(function() {
        image.src = (++img > imgMax ? (img = 1) : img) + '.jpg';
        }, 9000);
    }
     
</script>
```

```css
img {
    animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
    background: transparent;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="1" alt="Музей">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка главная. Вместо

> ```html
> <img id="image" src="1" alt="Музей">
> ```

должно быть

```html
<img id="image" src="1.jpg" alt="Музей">
```

Ошибка вторая. Этот код

```js
let i=1;
if(i!=0){setInterval(function() {
    image.src = (++img > imgMax ? (img = 1) : img) + '.jpg';
    }, 1000);
    i--;
} else {
    setInterval(function() {
    image.src = (++img > imgMax ? (img = 1) : img) + '.jpg';
    }, 9000);
}
```

бессмысленен. Т.к. `i` всегда равно 1. Поэтому достаточно

```js
setInterval(function() {
  image.src = (++img > imgMax ? (img = 1) : img) + '.jpg';
}, 1000);
```

Ну и перенести все в событие `DOMContentLoaded`

Answer (score 0):

Может быть картинка не успевает загрузиться? Попробуйте так

```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var img = 1, imgMax = 3;
    var image = document.getElementById('image');
    let i=1;
    if(i!=0){setInterval(function() {
        image.src = (++img > imgMax ? (img = 1) : img) + '.jpg';
        }, 1000);
        i--;
    } else {
        setInterval(function() {
        image.src = (++img > imgMax ? (img = 1) : img) + '.jpg';
        }, 9000);
    }
   });
```

Comment: Не совсем, проблема в следующем: оно как будто грузит не существующую картинку и из-за этого показывается то что на скриншоте, Но когда проходит интервал оно начинает работать нормально и сменять друг друга. Но так как мне надо большой интервал, оно выглядит не очень красиво. Я вот этим условием попытался быстро загрузить, а потом увеличить интервал смены картинок, но не получилось

Comment: @ПавелРейхерт У Вас неправильное значение атрибута `src` - `<img id="image" src="1.jpg" alt="Музей">`. Все остальное - тоже неправильно.

Comment: Этот код бессмысленный. При каких условиях выполнится блок `else`?